# Incorporating the jQuery UI draggable into website using divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the draggable jquery UI, however it doesn't work on my website. In the example that is given they have two ids, one called draggable and one called sortable. However in my website I only have one div called attraction. I have included the library and there are no errors, however it still isnt working.

[image] This is a screen shot of the div structure within my webpage. Each div called attraction is the thing I want to be able to drag, and change order of each of these divs. Does anyone know how I can incorporate the jquery ui into this? This is my code below in the JS

```
$( function() {
$( "#attraction" ).sortable({
  revert: true
});
$( "#attraction" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable: "#attraction",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid"
});
$( "div" ).disableSelection();
} );
```

In the HTML I am adding the div attraction into this div below, but I am doing that by javascript.

```
 <div id="itinerary_attractions" > 

        </div>
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: As divs are classed with `attraction` `$(".attraction").draggable` might be it.

Comment: @pmkro thanks for that but still isn't working

Comment: Hard to tell with the little amount of code you've posted, but it may be a result of dynamically adding the elements. Trying adding static HTML first to see if it works like that.

Comment: @RyanGibbs It can move the position of things in the div, but not the actual div itself

Comment: Consider putting together a jsfiddle or posting more of the code, so we have more to work with. It's hard to know what's wrong based off one snippet and a screenshot that's too small to read.

Comment: @RyanGibbs I would add more code but I have a lot of lines of code, I am adding the content through javascript so nothing is in the html page. I have tried to add a fiddle but the fiddle wouldn't work. I could send you a link to the website if you want to have a look. It is just going to be very hard to explain it without writing about 150 lines of code

Comment: I think you need a custom `handle` for both the Sortable and Draggable instances. You may also need a custom `helper` callback/`function` for the Draggable instance. [Try this Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jzMbdx) and see if it helps you.

Comment: When I get stuck I like to reduce the non-working section down to the essentials until I find the problem. As I said in your example, were it me, I'd toss a non-dynamically generated version in jsfiddle for experimentation.

Comment: @RyanGibbs this is a non working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ytawrhjc/3/ For some reason it wont let me add the css or html

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for this, although, I dont want to have buttons. I just want to automatically move the container

Comment: Not fully tested, but check this out: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvRNPd (You'd likely need to increase/adjust the height of the preview window.)

Comment: And another one with less CSS.. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEgKpo Hope this and the other help you. =) But basically, I gave some margins to the Draggable element, so that it can be, well, dragged.

Comment: @SallyCJ no this didn't work for me, would it be possible to chat to you about where i am going wrong? im not sure cause there is no errors

Comment: Try again: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEgKpo (I've just updated it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166993/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-ol12-9).